# Angular get dynamically created DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, dom

I am creating a Video Element in Angular and attaching it to the DOM. I may add multiple videos to the DOM. However trying to retreive this element is proving difficult.

The Element is created as follows:

```
    const idObject = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
    const canvas =  this.canvasComponent.activeCanvas;
    const url = vid.src;
    const videoE = this.canvasRenderer.createElement('video') as HTMLVideoElement;
    videoE.width = vid.videoWidth;
    videoE.height = vid.videoHeight;
    videoE.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    videoE.controls = true;
    videoE.id = idObject.toString();
    videoE.hidden = true;
    const source = this.canvasRenderer.createElement('source') as HTMLSourceElement;
    source.src = url;
    source.type = 'video/webm';
    videoE.appendChild(source);

    this.canvasRenderer.appendChild(this.elem.nativeElement, videoE);
```

canvasRenderer is angular component Renderer2

I can easily retreive the elemnt using

```
   document.getElementById(elementid)
```

I cannot access the element with Renderer2, ElementRef or ViewChild. These seem to require the jquery selector(#) to be present.

Is it good prcatice to use 'document.getElementById' in Angular ?

Is it possible to add jquery selector to the element being created?

Is there another way to get the desired DOM element by id?

Comment: Could you create the `video` elements in an `*ngFor` loop, instead of doing it in code?

Comment: You should not use dom manipulation like this, you should use angular components to render your videos. Create a video component and handle your logic in there.

Comment: @ConnorsFan the code dynamically creates the video element based on some other user interaction

Comment: @cloned could u elaborate more? What do you mean by 'Create a video component and handle your logic in there.'

Comment: If the user interaction generates items in an array, you could create the `video` elements with an `*ngFor` loop. That would be more natural in an Angular application.

Comment: [Basic overview for components](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components) Basically you have to create an `<app-video>` component which then takes care of rendering the video. Maybe you also need [some type of service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services)  which handles logic of which video is playing ...